# Sublime text 3 + emmet error with snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I think I broken my emmet.
 
When I write this :

```
div.row
```

And press tab I get that :

```
d<div class="ro"></div>
```

*The d before the marker is not a typo*

I remove and install again the package and then uninstall and re-install sublime... I don't know what to do now.

Please, help !